# Writing an advanced filtering system

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Here are my relationships

[image]

User wants to be able to add filters using a drop down menu and filter the Volunteers accordingly. Filters are coming from the `VolunteerWorkArea` table (`VolunteerWorkAreaId`). The way I'm going to do it painful and probably that's because lack of knowledge. Every time user adds a new filter, I have to change the SQL in a complex way. For example, this is the SQL after user adding three filters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Volunteer.VolunteerId AS Volunteer_VolunteerId ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerFirstName ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerLastName ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerOtherName ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerStreetAddress ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerSuburb ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerPostCode ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerHomePhone ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerMobilePhone ,
        Volunteer.VolunteerGender
FROM    Volunteer
        INNER JOIN ( VolunteerWorkArea
                     INNER JOIN VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation ON VolunteerWorkArea.VolunteerWorkAreaId = VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.VolunteerWorkAreaId
                   ) ON Volunteer.VolunteerId = VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.VolunteerId
WHERE   VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerWorkAreaId] = 17
        AND Volunteer.VolunteerId IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
                Volunteer.VolunteerId
        FROM    Volunteer
                INNER JOIN ( VolunteerWorkArea
                             INNER JOIN VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation ON VolunteerWorkArea.[VolunteerWorkAreaId] = VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerWorkAreaId]
                           ) ON Volunteer.[VolunteerId] = VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerId]
        WHERE   VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerWorkAreaId] = 16
                AND Volunteer.VolunteerId IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                        Volunteer.VolunteerId AS Volunteer_VolunteerId
                FROM    Volunteer
                        INNER JOIN ( VolunteerWorkArea
                                     INNER
JOIN VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation ON VolunteerWorkArea.[VolunteerWorkAreaId] = VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerWorkAreaId]
                                   ) ON Volunteer.[VolunteerId] = VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerId]
                WHERE   VolunteerWorkAreaAllocation.[VolunteerWorkAreaId] = 15 ) );
```

So every time user adds a filter, I have to change the SQL massively through code. I'm pretty sure there is an easy way to do this. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You have several instances of a join between `V`, `VWAA` and `VWA`, which I suggest you "encapsulate" into a view to simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want user to decide **volunteers** on the basis of **volunteerWorkArea** then easier solution will be using subform.

1. Create a new form that is not based on any table
2. Create and bind a combobox with **volunteerWorkArea** table using wizard
   (say **name: combo2**).
3. Create a subform and bind it with other two tables i.e. **volunteer** &
   **volunteerWorkAreaAllocation** (*Image has less number of fields for
   sample*)
4. Hide ID fields by setting visible property to false.
5. Set subform control properties as shown in image (**combo2** as master
   field and Child as **volunteerWorkAreaID**)

[image]

Comment: Really sorry for the very vary late reaction. I was away from IT for a while :(